# How to modify this program to make child sleep for 5 seconds?

Tags: c

I inserted the line sleep(5); to make child sleep for 5 seconds, but after compiling the code it generated the following output:

```
forkdemo.c:: In function 'main':
forkdemo.c:18:1: error: 'else' without a previous 'if' else.
```

How can I fix it so that I can make the child sleep without generating an error message after compiling the program?

Also, is the line I inserted to make parent wait for the child to complete its task correct?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

main()
{
int fork_rv;
printf("Before: my pid is %d\n",getpid());

fork_rv=fork();

if (fork_rv == -1)
perror("fork");
else if (fork_rv == 0) 
sleep(5); /* Line I inserted to make child sleep for 5 seconds */
printf ("I am the child. my pid=%d\n",getpid());
else
printf ("I am the parent. my child is %d\n",fork_rv);
wait(NULL); /* line I inserted to make parent wait for child. */
}
```

Comment: You need a few [good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read. You have a very basic error that no good (or bad for that matter) book or tutorial or course would have taught you.

Comment: Never mind the forking and sleeping, just try to write `if...else if...else...` correctly. If you can't get that to work, try `if...else...`. If you can't get that to work, just try `if...`. **Simplify.**

Answer (score 2):

You should use blaces `{}` to build a block from multiple statements for use in `if` statement (and others like `for`).

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

main()
{
    int fork_rv;
    printf("Before: my pid is %d\n",getpid());

    fork_rv=fork();

    if (fork_rv == -1) {
        perror("fork");
    } else if (fork_rv == 0) {
        sleep(5); /* Line I inserted to make child sleep for 5 seconds */
        printf ("I am the child. my pid=%d\n",getpid());
    } else {
        printf ("I am the parent. my child is %d\n",fork_rv);
        wait(NULL); /* line I inserted to make parent wait for child. */
    }
}
```

Comment: i had a feeling it might be the braces problem

Comment: This is still not valid C++.

Comment: You mean CodeBlocks is more than just the name of an IDE?